# Placepicker works only after doubletap

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Quite annoying, that my google place working only if user did double click .

Why it is happening?

My code, where place picker initialized

```
etLocationD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // findPlace();
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), 101);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO: Handle the error.
   }
}
    });
```

My .xml VIEW

```
 <com.easyjob.meistars.utils.InputFieldView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <com.easyjob.meistars.utils.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/etLocationD"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
                android:hint="@string/your_location"
                android:editable="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="" />
        </com.easyjob.meistars.utils.InputFieldView>
```

On application user must click double on field to get place picker opened.

When place is selected and If user staying in the same view, he can change his location by doing only 1 click - this flow is OK.

But if he leaves this VIEW and go back to change location, then again ... double click :(

What Did i wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try adding this property to your `EditText`

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```